# Как реализовать равномерную интерполяцию в Unity

Tags: unity3d, интерполяция

Никак не могу добиться правильной интерполяции между двумя точками, алгоритм у меня следующий

Есть 2 точки и есть время за которое объект должен их пройти.
Время в данном примере = 0.1 сек

```
 void Update()
{
if(flagJourney == false)
{
     endPosition = P1;
     startMarker = transform;
     startTime = Time.time;
     flagJourney = true;
}
else
{
     float prec = (Time.time - startTime) / (0.1f);
     if(prec  >= 1)
     {
          flagJourney = false;
          if(prec  > 1)
              prec = 1;
     }
     transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endPosition, prec);
     Debug.Log(Vector3.Distance(transform.position, endPosition)); // вывод дистанции, которую проходит объект за 1 проход
}
}
```

[image: вывод консоли]
Как видно из скриншота, объект за примерно 100 миллисекунд проделал крайне не равномерный путь, данные точки могут примерно напомнить экспоненциальную функцию. Мне же надо чтобы объект на протяжении 100 млс двигался со средней скоростью, ибо данное решение приводит к рывкам, если его перенести в проект, где точки нужно брать из массива, тогда ни о каком гладком перемещении речи идти не может.

Comment: fixedUpdate,time.deltaTime(time.fixedDeltaTime) что не подходит?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы каждый раз считаете разницу от прошедшего времени и высчитываете отклонение с начала запуска кадра.

Ошибка в коде у вас вот здесь

```
transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startMarker.position, endPosition, prec);
```

Вы `startmarker` ранее назначили ссылкой на свой собственный `transform`. Сделайте переменную вектором и назначьте в нее позицию трансформа при старте и все должно быть ок.

Обычно для таких целей используют относительное время, для метода `Update` это `Time.deltaTime`, это время между отдельными кадрами, для физики в методе `FixedUpdate` используют `Time.fixedDeltaTime`.

Время между вызовами отрисовки величина непостоянная, но в целом для глаза это как правило не заметно. А вот для физики вызовы в зависимости от настроек могут идти друг за другом и время после старта системы уже не будет показателем. Поэтому в методе `FixedUpdate` используют `Time.fixedDeltaTime` как время используемое `Unity` для расчета очередной итерации физики.